# AVR Interrupts, Setting port values while in the interrupt

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr

I'm using a tiny2313 microcontroller in AVR assembly. I have an external interrupt controlled by a momentary switch. The interrupt is working correctly, and jumps to the routine when the button is pressed.

However, I want to set a bit ON in port D while "in" the interrupt routine (an LED indicator) and then turn it off when exiting the routine.

All "seems" to be working, but the pin never goes high. I'm guessing that the port won't be updated while in the interrupt, so I set it high, do some stuff (which takes a few seconds) then set it low, and nothing seems to happen.

I tried finding some documentation to confirm this is the issue but don't see anything. Am I on the right road, and if so, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Being "in" an interrupt routine is not that special of a situation for the processor.  It may have some internal flags set differently (like interrupts being off) but ought to work the same for things like toggling bits on ports.  That being said, are you able to toggle that led in a main/non-interrupt routine?

Comment: Yes, no problem toggling leds in the main routine. Everything else works. I also put my scope on the pin of the controller to make sure my led wasn't defective or the breadboard pins were making poor contact!

Comment: Your guess is incorrect. You can set the pin value in the interrupt. There will be another problem. Provide code interrupt routine and the code enabling the interrupt.

Comment: This is a a common developing/debugging procedure to "see" the duration of some part of the program, and of course it works in interrupt service routines, too. So your problem lies somewhere else. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Just note that in the debugger, everything worked properly. See answer below, as it was a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a hardware issue. The interrupt pin was being shorted accidentally by a bad switch which was causing all sort of other issues.